# Why did Palpatine say: "I am all the Sith"?

Tags: star-wars, sith, the-rise-of-skywalker

In the ninth Star Wars movie, when Palpatine is fighting Rey, he says: *I am all the Sith.*

Why did he say that? Has he done something that made him "connect" and/or obtain the power of all the Sith before him?

If not, is he saying that because he is over powered? (And yet he dies the same way as before...)

Comment: @Valorum: :-D I'll admit that I expected you to quote from the Junior Novelization. I personally haven't found anything definitive, but there are a lot of theories, including a fairly common fan theory that one of the reasons the Rule of Two has worked is that, in death, the Sith join into a mass of knowledge that the current Master can draw upon.

To some degree, he is, though. Rule of two, and his apprentice is dead.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - In a very literal sense he's "*all the Sith [that are alive at present]*" but I very much doubt that's what's meant.

Comment: And, if I recall correctly, the stadium of people in the background are all Sith Cultists and Loyalists, but yeah. My read on the line is that he wasn't necessarily speaking of that he was drawing power from his Sith ancestors, but rather that he was the end result of all of those millenia of Sith development, now finally in position to take power as they were always meant to. Kind of arrogant, really.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - The Sith cultists aren't Force users. Their power is negligible

Comment: That being said, the Temple itself is a major source of dark side Force power.

Comment: Being the Senate was not good enough for him anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [StarWars databank article on Palpatine](https://www.starwars.com/databank/emperor-palpatine-darth-sidious) indicates that Palpatine is a '*vessel of all of the Sith's power*'. Although this is a pretty ambiguous statement, the fact that this is then contrasted with Rey being assisted by the '*spirits of the departed Jedi*' would suggest that they mean this in a literal sense (e.g. of him somehow drawing on the the power of the Sith masters who'd come before him) rather than a figurative sense of being the product of their hard work.

> Rey resisted him with the help of Ben, who’d returned to the light.
> But their defiance gave Sidious a new opportunity – he would drain the
> energy of their Force dyad to restore his own body, then rule alone.
> **Though Sidious was a vessel of all the Sith’s power, his granddaughter
> was assisted by the spirits of the departed Jedi.** Rey turned his fell
> power back at him, destroying him.